# How to migrate from "Pay-As-You-Go" SQL Server VM to standard Windows VM with perpetual SQL Server license

Tags: sql-server, azure

We currently operate two (2) VM’s on our Azure cloud configured into an Availability Group (AG) for SQL Server DB workloads. We use “Pay-As-You-Go” licensing model for SQL Server operation in these VM’s. We recently purchased a set of perpetual licenses for SQL Server software and we are planning to soon deploy new set of Windows VM’s (with manual SQL Server software installation) to replace current “PAYG” nodes.

I would like to know whether there is a method (recommended by Microsoft or otherwise proven) to insert new SQL Server VM’s in operation and remove old “PAYG” systems without causing any down-time on DB workloads.

Please, advise.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cluster and AO Availability Group are working and healthy. All you need is to add new secondaries to the set, i.e. the new Windows VMs with SQL Server manually installed. As soon as the databases are synchronized, you can switch the primary to be one of the new servers and then you can start decommissioning the older VMs. This process won't cause any downtime to your environment. The article below explains the setup of HA SQL Servers, but I assume you already have this:

[Configure Always On Availability Group in Azure VM manually](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-availability-group-tutorial)